# Как сделать чтоб иконки были горизонтально?

Tags: html, css

```css
.vk {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: flex;
}
.vk img {
  margin: auto;
}
.fb {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: flex;
}
.fb img {  
  margin: auto;
}
.ins {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: flex;
}
.ins img {  
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="vk">
    <img src="img/vk-icon.svg" alt="Вк">
   </div>
   <div class="fb">
    <img src="img/fb-icon.svg" alt="фб">
   </div>
   <div class="ins">
    <img src="img/insta-icon.svg" alt="вк">
   </div>
```

Comment: [tutorial](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните их в один блок и примените `display: flex`
Подробнее про flexbox на [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.vk {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: flex;
}

.vk img {
  margin: auto;
}

.fb {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: flex;
}

.fb img {
  margin: auto;
}

.ins {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid none;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #e1e1e1;
  display: flex;
}

.ins img {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="vk">
    <img src="img/vk-icon.svg" alt="Вк">
  </div>
  <div class="fb">
    <img src="img/fb-icon.svg" alt="фб">
  </div>
  <div class="ins">
    <img src="img/insta-icon.svg" alt="вк">
  </div>
</div>
```